# fetch specific value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phpmyadmin

I have the an array coming from this code

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION["followers"]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Array is

```
Array
(
    [pagination] => Array
        (
        )

    [meta] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => SD
                    [profile_picture] => https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_4.jpg
                    [id] => 42114932
                    [full_name] => A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => ER
                    [profile_picture] => https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t51.2885-19/1.jpg
                    [id] => 395834289
                    [full_name] => P
                )

        )

)
```

i want to know that is it possible to match specific value from array and then fetch other values related to it,

e.g
I am getting value of id = 42114932, now i wish to match this value in the given array and wherever it matches, i wish to fetch the username, fullname and profile pic of that id, 
in this case corresponding to id 42114932 i wish to get

```
username=SD, 
full_nmae=A
profile_pic = https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_4.jpg
```

if it is possible can anyone tell how it can be done

Comment: could you solve it? you should say which answer helped you!

Answer (score 0):

An option is to loop trough the array

```
$f = ..;  //(the id to find)
for($i = 0, $i < count($data); i++)
{
    if($data[$i]['id'] == $f){
        echo 'Full name : '.$data[$i]['fullname'];
        echo '<br />Username : '.$data[$i]['username'];
        echo '<br />Profile picture : '.$data[$i]['profile_pic'];
    }
}
```

I think this could work? might want to tweak the counter of the for loop.

Comment: i was getting syntax error so i changed for loop to   for($i = 0; $i < count($data); i++) but still i am getting syntax error saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR

Comment: seems like I forgot a `$` for the last i in the loop try that.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you :

```
  $arr = $_SESSION["followers"]['data'];
    $id = 42114932;
    $count = count($arr);
    $foundArr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i< $count; $i++) {
       if ($arr['id'] == $id) {
         $foundArr[$i] = $arr[$i];
         break;
       }
    }
    print_r($foundArr)
```

Comment: In reply i am getting only this result:   Array ( )

Answer (score 0):

The Code below is self explanatory:

```
<?php
$_SESSION["followers"];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION["followers"]);
echo "</pre>";



$yourID = 42114932;
for($x=0;$x<(count($_SESSION["followers"]['data']));$x++){
    if($yourID  == $_SESSION["followers"]['data'][$x]['id']){ //compare your id to each record
        echo "Full name : ".$array['data'][$x]['full_name'];
        echo "<br>Username : ".$array['data'][$x]['username'];
        echo "<br>Profile picture : ".$array['data'][$x]['profile_picture'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not able to fetch the data, although there are no error but there are no results also

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMetaInfo(array $array, $id, $arrayBranch = NULL){ 
    if($arrayBranch === NULL){
        return FALSE;
    }

    $returnArray = array();

    foreach($array[$arrayBranch] as $key => $value){
         if($value['id'] == $id){
              unset($value['id']);
              $returnArray[$id] = $value;
              return $returnArray;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: did not get any result

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 $row = fetchData($_SESSION["followers"]['data'], 'id', 42114932); // Here you will get the comlet row of data you are searching

function fetchData($data, $column, $value){
    for($i = 0, $i < count($data), i++)
    {
        if($data[$i][$column] == $value){
            return $data[$i]; // returns a complete row.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC, expecting ';'

Comment: there was a ';' instead a ',' in the for clause!